# DB2 SQL Web Pagination - How to tell I reach EOF

Tags: sql, web, pagination, fetch, db2-400

Friends,
I am trying to find a very simple solution to tell me I have reach the End of file with a Web Pagination, using Fetch Next. I am using Previous & Next button to trigger stored procedure.

```
**FREE                                                                                              
// RFC Main Grid                                                                                    

CTL-OPT NOMAIN OPTION (*SRCSTMT : *NODEBUGIO);                                                      

DCL-PROC PUR027 EXPORT;                                                                             
  DCL-PI PUR027 EXTPROC(*DCLCASE);                                                                  
    StartingRow PACKED(3:0);                                                                        
    NbrOfRows PACKED(3:0);                                                                          
    TotalRows CHAR(10);                                                                             
    RowCount CHAR(10);                                                                              
    Search CHAR(30);                                                                                
    EndOfFile CHAR(3);                                                                              
    BOF CHAR(1);                                                                                    
    EOF CHAR(1);                                                                                    
    RSL CHAR(2);                                                                                    
  END-PI;                                                                                           

  IF Search = '';                                                                                     

    EXEC SQL 
      Declare RSCURSOR cursor for                                                              
        SELECT CDEPT, CDESC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CDESC, CDEPT) as ROWNUMBER                        
          FROM CDPL03                                                                                       
          ORDER BY CDESC, CDEPT                                                                             
          OFFSET (:StartingRow - 1) * :NbrOfRows ROWS                                                       
          FETCH NEXT :NbrOfRows ROWS ONLY;                                                                  

    EXEC SQL  Open RSCURSOR;                                                                          

    EXEC SQL SET RESULT SETS Cursor RSCURSOR;                                                         

  ELSE;                                                                                               

    EXEC SQL 
      Declare RSCURSOR2 cursor for                                                             
        SELECT CDEPT, CDESC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CDESC, CDEPT) as ROWNUMBER                        
          FROM CDPL03                                                                                       
          WHERE CDESC LIKE '%' concat trim(:Search) concat '%' OR                                           
                CDEPT LIKE '%' concat trim(:Search) concat '%'                                              
          ORDER BY CDESC, CDEPT                                                                             
          OFFSET (:StartingRow - 1) * :NbrOfRows ROWS                                                       
          FETCH NEXT :NbrOfRows ROWS ONLY;                                                                  

    EXEC SQL  Open RSCURSOR2;                                                                         

    EXEC SQL SET RESULT SETS Cursor RSCURSOR2;                                                        

  ENDIF;                                                                                              

  // Begin & End of File                                                                              
  IF StartingRow = 1;                                                                                 
    BOF = '1';                                                                                        
    EOF = '0';                                                                                        
  ELSE;                                                                                               
    BOF = '0';                                                                                        
    EOF = '0';                                                                                        
  ENDIF;                                                                                              

  // Validate for SQL errors                                                                          
  IF SQLSTATE = '00000';                                                                              
    RSL = '00';                                                                                       
    //TotalRows2 = %CHAR(TotalRows);                                                                  
  ELSEIF SQLSTATE = '02000';                                                                          
    RSL = '10';                                                                                       
  ELSE;                                                                                               
    RSL = '20';                                                                                       
  ENDIF;                                                                                              

  RETURN;                                                                                             

END-PROC PUR027;                                                                                    


// To create the service program:                                                                   
//           CRTSRVPGM SRVPGM(BPCSO/PUR027WS)                                                       
//            MODULE(BPCSO/PUR027W)                                                                 
//            SRCFILE(BPCSS/PURBNDF) SRCMBR(PUR027WB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading multiple records in a block, I retrieve the number of records fetched with `GET DIAGNOSTICS` like this:

```
exec sql get diagnostics
  :cnt = row_count;
```

Then if the number of records fetched is less than the requested number of records, I know that I am on the last page.

There is a problem with this method though. If the last page is full, you don't know it until you try to read the next page, and it is empty. So one way to handle that is to request one record more than you are going to present on the page.  That is, if you are presenting 25 records per page, request 26. If your result set has 26 records, then there is at least one record on the next page. Still only present 25 records, and increment your offset by 25 records each time, just request 26 records. If the record set has less than 26 records, then you know you are on the last page.

Comment: I like that. Simple solution. I will add one more record to my search and when I display back on the web I wont post the extra record if there is one.

Comment: One more question that is not related to this one. Do you know where I can find documentation to make my Query dynamic?

Comment: In the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafydynamic.htm)

Comment: Try it out, if you have more questions, ask again. If the question deals with embedding SQL in RPG, tag it with RPGLE as well as DB2-400

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQLERRD(2)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzfielddescsqlca.htm)

> For an OPEN statement, if the cursor is insensitive to changes, SQLERRD(2) contains the actual number of rows in the result set. If the cursor is sensitive to changes, SQLERRD(2) contains an estimated number of rows in the result set.

You can also use [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzgetdiag.htm) after the open for the same info...

> **DB2_NUMBER_ROWS**
>   If the previous SQL statement was an OPEN or a FETCH which caused the size of the result table to be known, returns the number of rows in the result table. For SENSITIVE cursors, this value can be thought of as an approximation since rows inserted and deleted will affect the next retrieval of this value. Otherwise, the value zero is returned.

Key point for both, for an exact count, you'd need to declare your cursor `INSENSITIVE` which will create a copy of your selected rows so that inserts, deletes and updates don't affect the results.  There's also a performance hit.